# Pointer-events : Enable and Disable selectively. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pointer-events

In following Next.js Component i want to add  hover effects to the **.itemCard** and the **button** only. Those two must have diffent hover effects.
(ex- itemcard will have a box-shadow effect and the button will have a backgroud color change).
I have tried pinter-events:none in various ways but had no luck.

```
const Img = (props: imgProps) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.itemCard}>
      <div className={styles.imagecontainer}>
        <div className={styles.imageOuter}>
          <img className={styles.imageItself} src={props.img} alt="" />
        </div>
          <div className={styles.details}>
            <h3 className={styles.titleCardHome}>{props.title}</h3>
            <p className={styles.description}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
            <p className={styles.priceHome}>{props.price}</p>
            <button className={styles.btncartAdd}>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my janky CSS:

```
.itemCard {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    max-width: 20rem;
    min-width: 15rem;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    transition: .3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.imagecontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    max-width: 20rem;
    min-width: 15rem;
    background-color: rgb(234, 202, 117);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
    transition: .3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.139);
}

.imagecontainer .imageOuter {
    max-height: 60%;
    min-height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}




.imagecontainer .imageOuter img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.itemCard :not(.btncartAdd):hover{
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    /* transform: scale(1.01); */
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.214);
}
.details :not(.btncartAdd) {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
.itemCard
.details {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: -50px 5px -30px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(254, 229, 160);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.details .btncartAdd {
    background-color: rgb(223, 84, 20);
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [`:hover` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) then?

Comment: When you say you want to have the hover effect 'only' on .itemCard - it seems to be that it will take effect wherever the user hovers on the card. Are you saying the problem is getting a different effect when they hover over the button - i.e. for it then not to look like a hover on the whole card?